# Mysql : how to calculate business hrs between two timestamps and neglect weekends

Tags: mysql, sql, date

My table has sample data and I need to calculate business hrs between two timestamps in two columns. Business hrs : 9:00am to 5:00pm and neglect Saturday and Sunday, I am not considering public holidays. Can someone please provide some guidelines on how to achieve this?   I want desired output as stated in column 3 , date is in format of : yyyy-mm-dd

```
    Created date             Updated date         Business hrs
    2012-03-05 9:00am   2012-03-05 3:00pm             6
    2012-03-05 10:00am  2012-03-06 10:00am            9
    2012-03-09 4:00pm   2012-03-19 10:00am            2
```

Comment: what you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: scratching my head on logic and starters would be good

Comment: for some starting point see my answer below...

Answer (score 25):

The question says that public holidays should not be considered, so this answer does just that - calculates business hours taking weekends into account, but ignoring possible public holidays.

If you need to take public holidays into account you'd need to have a separate table which would list dates for public holidays, which may differ from year to year and from state to state or country to country. The main formula may stay the same, but you'd need to subtract from its result hours for public holidays that fall within the given range of dates.

Let's create a table with some sample data that covers various cases:

```
CREATE TABLE T (CreatedDate datetime, UpdatedDate datetime);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('2012-03-05 09:00:00', '2012-03-05 15:00:00'), -- simple part of the same day
('2012-03-05 10:00:00', '2012-03-06 10:00:00'), -- full day across the midnight
('2012-03-05 11:00:00', '2012-03-06 10:00:00'), -- less than a day across the midnight
('2012-03-05 10:00:00', '2012-03-06 15:00:00'), -- more than a day across the midnight
('2012-03-09 16:00:00', '2012-03-12 10:00:00'), -- over the weekend, less than 7 days
('2012-03-06 16:00:00', '2012-03-15 10:00:00'), -- over the weekend, more than 7 days
('2012-03-09 16:00:00', '2012-03-19 10:00:00'); -- over two weekends
```

In MS SQL Server I use the following formula:

```
SELECT
    CreatedDate,
    UpdatedDate,
    DATEDIFF(minute, CreatedDate, UpdatedDate)/60.0 -
    DATEDIFF(day,    CreatedDate, UpdatedDate)*16 -
    DATEDIFF(week,   CreatedDate, UpdatedDate)*16 AS BusinessHours
FROM T
```

Which produces the following result:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|       CreatedDate       |       UpdatedDate       | BusinessHours |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| 2012-03-05 09:00:00     | 2012-03-05 15:00:00     | 6             |
| 2012-03-05 10:00:00     | 2012-03-06 10:00:00     | 8             |
| 2012-03-05 11:00:00     | 2012-03-06 10:00:00     | 7             |
| 2012-03-05 10:00:00     | 2012-03-06 15:00:00     | 13            |
| 2012-03-09 16:00:00     | 2012-03-12 10:00:00     | 2             |
| 2012-03-06 16:00:00     | 2012-03-15 10:00:00     | 50            |
| 2012-03-09 16:00:00     | 2012-03-19 10:00:00     | 42            |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

It works, because in SQL Server [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) returns the count of the specified *datepart* boundaries crossed between the specified *startdate* and *enddate*.

Each day has 8 business hours. I calculate total number of hours between two dates, then subtract the number of midnights multiplied by 16 non-business hours per day, then subtract the number of weekends multiplied by 16 (8+8 business hours for Sat+Sun).

**It also assumes that the given start and end date/times are during the business hours.**

In MySQL the closest equivalent is [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), but it works differently. It effectively calculates the difference in seconds and divides (discarding the fractional part) by the number of seconds in the chosen *unit*.

So, to get results that we need we can calculate the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` between some anchor datetime and `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate` instead of calculating the difference between `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate` directly.

I've chosen `2000-01-03 00:00:00`, which is a Monday. You can choose any other Monday (or Sunday, if your week starts on Sunday) midnight for the anchor date.

The MySQL query becomes (see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc2a2/1/0)):

```
SELECT
    CreatedDate,
    UpdatedDate,

    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CreatedDate, UpdatedDate)/60.0 -

    16*(
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,    '2000-01-03',UpdatedDate)-
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,    '2000-01-03',CreatedDate)
    ) -

    16*(
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,   '2000-01-03',UpdatedDate)-
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,   '2000-01-03',CreatedDate)
    ) AS BusinessHours

FROM T
```

Comment: This would seem to work for potential business hours, but actual business hours with holidays that change year to year would need explicit definition somewhere, likely in a table.

Comment: @JRD, you are right. The question clearly states that public holidays should be ignored and I didn't repeat it in the answer. I guess, I'd better do it...

Comment: A very clever solution, nonetheless.

Comment: It says (and I can confirm) that it only works if "the given start and end date/times are during the business hours" -- but I don't see where the business hours (8 to 5? 9 to 6? or etc.) are defined. But I can confirm that it doesn't work for work times outside the norm, I just don't know what the "norm" is in this example.

Comment: @SteveHarrington, the norm is 8 business hours per day. It doesn't matter when they start and end, the formula doesn't care. The formula subtracts 16 hours out of 24 hours for each calendar day. Then it subtracts additional hours for each weekend that happens to be inside the given range of dates. If your business day has, say, 10 business hours instead of 8, then you need to change 16 (=24-8) to 14 (=24-10) in the first part of the formula and second 16 (=8+8) to 20 (=10+10).

Comment: @VladimirBaranov thanks for your explanation, I understand that portion now. I still see odd results that I don't fully understand. Here's an example of business hours that were calculated for the given start/end dates: start: 2017-03-31 09:25:19.0 end: 2017-04-03 07:42:53.0 business hours calculated: 6.2833 -- seems strange somehow. I think it's assuming that the work day starts @ 7:42AM in this case?

Comment: @SteveHarrington, let's use a simpler example. Start `2017-03-30 09:30:00`, end `2017-03-31 07:45:00`. Formula gives 6.25 hours. It assumes that both `09:30` and `07:45` are within business hours. What these business hours could be? For 8 hrs/day they could be, say, `07:00-15:00`. Now, 15:00-09:30=5.5hrs plus 07:45-07:00 = 0.75hrs. 5.5+0.75=6.25. If business hours are, say, `06:00-14:00`, then 14:00-09:30=4.5hrs plus 07:45-06:00=1.75hrs; 4.5+1.75=6.25. End result is the same 6.25hrs. It **does not depend** on the start and end time of the business day, as long as its duration is the same 8hrs

Comment: @SteveHarrington, the formula assumes that the work day starts at some moment before `07:42` and ends 8 hours later. The work day can start at `07:42`, or at `05:00`, or at `06:30`, end result would be the same, because the work day duration should be 8 hours in any case, regardless of when the work day starts.

Answer (score 4):

Create a table called BusinessHours, with a single column called Hour containing a date time. Make Hour the primary key. Write a process to populate it with every business hour of the year (`2012-01-02 00:90:00, 2012-01-02 00:10:00` etc). This shouldn't be hard as the rules are straightforward. It sounds like a lot of data, but in the grand scheme of things it isn't (there are only 8760 hours in a year - even if your date time takes 8 bytes each, this is a whopping 60kB). Make sure to schedule a job to keep it populated.

Then:

```
Select
  y.CreatedDate,
  y.UpdatedDate,
  Count(*) as BusinessHours
From
  YourTable y
    Inner Join
  BusinessHours h
    On h.Hour >= y.CreatedDate And h.Hour < y.UpdatedDate
Group By
  y.CreatedDate,
  y.UpdatedDate
```

This also gives you a fairly straightforward approach if you do ever consider public holidays - just take the rows out of the BusinessHours table.

Answer (score 1):

Use datediff to calculate the diff between the start and the end time and then subtract (date_add with negative hours) the non-working hours: 24 for weekend days, 16 for working days expect the ending and starting day which needs additional calculation.
Whether a day is weekend day or not, can be specified with the dayofweek method.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT (FLOOR(DATEDIFF (UpdatedDate, CreatedDate) / 7) * 5 + MOD (DATEDIFF (UpdatedDate, CreatedDate), 7)) * 8 +
       TIMEDIFF (TIME (UpdatedDate), TIME(CreatedDate))
FROM YourTable
```

The above is not complete as it only "estimates" the weekends... but it should get you started... another option is to work with a table of valid businesshours (for details see [this answer from Laurence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13426293/847363)).

For reference see [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).