# How to calculate business hours/minutes between two dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to understand how to calculate business hours between 7PM and 7AM.

For Example I have:

- Start time:  `2018-01-10 19:15:00`
- End time:  `2018-01-11 09:00:00`

I expect calculation to return (11:45:00) between **7PM and 7AM.**

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Because hours between 7am and 7pm will be 12hrs. And what does it have to do with start time and end time?

Comment: Provide some sample output to get clear vision to what are you looking for.

Comment: For example, Starttime  2018-08-01 12:35 and Endtime 2018-08-01 21:55, here is 2 hours 55 minutes after 7PM. that's the time I am looking for, Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you really mean tsql and mysql?

Comment: Trying to get with tsql.

Comment: You may find [Mysql : how to calculate business hrs between two timestamps and neglect weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13426186/4116017) useful. There is answer there for SQL Server and for MySQL.

Comment: That gives hours between two time stamps, here I need only extra hours after 7 PM if Start time before 7 PM.

Comment: Don't forget to consider weekends and holidays...

Comment: "That gives hours between two time stamps"..well think about it, the first timestamp will be 7pm (or your start time, whichever is later), the second timestamp is your end time (or 7am the following day, whichever is earlier). Using those will give you the hours in between

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not very clear, however this should be a good query to start from:

```
declare @tmp table(StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime)

insert into @tmp values
 ('2018-07-01 19:35:00', '2018-07-01 21:55:00')
,('2018-08-01 12:35:00', '2018-08-01 21:55:00')
,('2018-08-01 12:35:00', '2018-08-02 05:55:00')
,('2018-08-01 12:35:00', '2018-08-02 07:00:00')
,('2018-08-01 12:35:00', '2018-08-02 07:15:00')

SELECT StartTime
    ,EndTime
    ,CASE 
        WHEN StartTime < dateadd(HOUR, 19, cast(cast(StartTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
            THEN convert(VARCHAR(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(MINUTE, dateadd(HOUR, 19, cast(cast(StartTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME)), 
                CASE 
                    WHEN endtime < DATEADD(HOUR, 7, cast(DATEADD(day, 1, cast(StartTime AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
                        THEN endtime
                    ELSE DATEADD(HOUR, 7, cast(DATEADD(day, 1, cast(StartTime AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
                    END), 0), 114)
        ELSE NULL
        END AS Extra_time
FROM @tmp
```

Results with different test cases:

[image]

*Note: extra time is capped at 12:00 because you want working hours between 7PM and 7AM*

*Note 2: extra time is computed only if Start time is before 7 PM because in comments you wrote: "I need only extra hours after 7 PM if Start time before 7 PM"*

Comment: Thanks @Andrea, that's what I am looking for.                                                    
Sorry..my intention is to calculate the time from 7PM to 7AM, *irrespective of StartTime.                                                                                                              
Just a quick question, in same query is it possible to calculate first test case hours (02:20).